# Java swing timer when delay is set to 0?

Tags: java, swing

When the delay is set to 0, what is the interval for the listener to be called?

I tried changing delay to various values, but my listener was capped at about 60 times per second, unless I changed it to larger value like 100. Is 60 fps the defualt value? How can I increase the fps?

```
public class test {
    static long previousTime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println((currentTime - previousTime) / 1000d);
                previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        });

        timer.start();

        while (true);
    }
}
```

This is the code I tested with. When delay is not big enough, it prints around 0.015.

Comment: maybe this is capped by your CPU or operation system? can you verify that other applications on the same technology are able to interact faster?

Comment: There are a lot of things which would effect the timer - OS thread scheduling and system overheads; your own code efficiencies, for example Swing `Timer` uses a "coalescing"  mechanism which prevents it from posting more events onto the Event Dispatching Queue while previously pending events are still in the event queue

Comment: I've used Swing `Timer`s set to 5 milliseconds without issue in the past, maybe consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Whatever number you set it to, never trust the timer to be completely precise, and instead base your animation delta translations on measured time differences.

Comment: ^-- That's actually a really good point, `Timer` and `Thread.sleep` only guarantee a "at least" amount of delay